# How to get the id of the element clicked using jQuery

Tags: jquery, click

```
<div class="main_div">
    <div id="inner_div">    
        <span id="d1" class="get_clicked">click to get id</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to get the id of the clicked element? The span which is present inside the inner_div will be having different ids because I will be loading the span from the model(MVC) using jquery ajax. So there will be 'n' number of span. All the span will have unique id. I want to get the id of the span which I click.

How the get the id of the span when clicked? How to do this using jQuery?

Comment: the span is still being loaded via ajax right?

Comment: yes, I am loading the span using jquery ajax.

Comment: is `inner div` or `main_div` loaded by ajax?

Comment: inner_div is loaded using ajax.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

update as you loading contents dynamically so you use.

```
$(document).on('click', 'span', function () {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

old code

```
$('span').click(function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

or you can use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('span').on('click', function () {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

`this` refers to current span element clicked

`this.id` will give the `id` of the current span clicked

Comment: the span is being loaded via ajax so that wont work, you have to use delegate handlers instead

Comment: @DGS i have used `.on`

Comment: That doesnt make a difference. Will still only bind events to the elements currently in the DOM

Comment: The first two still wont

Comment: Thank you very much @TusharGupta its working now. can you explain the logic behind it?

Comment: @user2758150 as you loaded contents dynamically through AJAX the normal code won't work. You have to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: OK OK. Likewise I have two more contents which I am going to load dynamically. For example two buttons. So should I follow the same logic for them as well?

Comment: You have to specifically use Delegated `.on()` since `.on()` can be used as Direct or Delegated where direct is the same thing as doing `.bind()`

Comment: For that I have specify the tag name right? The jquery which will search through the whole document and then find the element which is clicked. correct?

Comment: @user2758150 `$(document).on( eventName, selector, function(){} );`

Comment: @user2758150 welocme :) Happy to help :)

Comment: @TusharGupta take a look over this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680213/what-is-workflow-of-the-react-js

Answer (score 10):

Since you are loading in the spans via ajax you will have to attach delegate handlers to the events to catch them as they bubble up.

```
$(document).on('click','span',function(e){
    console.log(e.target.id)
})
```

you will want to attach the event to the closest static member you can to increase efficiency.

```
$('#main_div').on('click','span',function(e){
    console.log(e.target.id)
})
```

is better than binding to the document for instance.

This question may help you understand

[Direct vs. Delegated - jQuery .on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to share how you can use this to change a attribute of the button, because it took me some time to figure it out...

For example in order to change it's background to yellow:

```
$("#"+String(this.id)).css("background-color","yellow");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id of clicked one by this code

```
$("span").on("click",function(e){
    console.log(e.target.Id);
});
```

Use `.on()` event for future compatibility