# How to get the id of clicked area but not the parent id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[How to get the id of the element clicked using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680735/how-to-get-the-id-of-the-element-clicked-using-jquery) this question have the answer of get the id of clicked element.

But it gives the all id.

For example

```
  <div id="major">
    <div id="two">  </div>
  </div>
```

When clicking the div `two` I want to get the `id` only one which is `two`. But the following script will give parent id also.

```
    $("body").on('click','div',function() 
    {   
        alert(this.id);
    });    //It alerts the two and major. But i want two only.
```

For this, purpose i tried to put the some undeclared function it gives result what i expect. For example

```
$("body").on('click','div',function() 
{   
    alert(this.id);
    mkh(); #undeclared function
});
```

Is there any inbuild method for to do it.? [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fq86U/92/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stop parent **[event propagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** to child element:

```
$("body").on('click','div',function(e){   
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert(this.id);
  mkh(); #undeclared function
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/05t43b9a/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.target` object.

```js
$("body").on('click', 'div', function(e) {
  alert(e.target.id);
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
#two {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
#major {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="major">
  <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not changing the target element.

Event object can be used to serve the purpose.
`$(event.target)` will give current target element
Using `event.stopPropagation()` to stop propagation(`bubbling`) of event when you click on inner div. Otherwise you will see two alerts of inner & outer div

```
    $("body").on('click','div',function(event) 
    {   event.stopPropagation();
   var _getId = $(event.target).attr('id');
    alert(_getId);

    });
```

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/fq86U/93/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not too hard. Watch this:

```
$("body").on('click','#two',function() 
    {   
        alert(this.id);
    });
```