# on click asp.net button in a listview

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lsvAccessMode" ClientIDMode="Static" OnItemDataBound="lsvAccessMode_ItemDataBound">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <asp:RadioButton runat="server" clientidmode="static" CssClass="customSelectBox disabled" ID="rbAccessMode" GroupName="accessMode" Enabled='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsSelected"))%>'  />
            <div class="customBox disabled" id="customBox">
                <strong><%# Eval("Decode1") %></strong><br>
                <img src="<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>" style="height: 80px"><br>
                <span class="help-block"><%# Eval("Decode2") %></span>
            </div>
        </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I have the following code above. So when i click one of the buttons above, it will append a class to it. But I am facing the following problem, i do not know what to insert into id portion of the `$(' ').click` function.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: Which button, which class?

Comment: it contains three radio button and i am unsure what to put in the $(' ').click bracket. Usually we put the id name then .ClientID but it does not work here.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the css class?

`$('.customSelectBox')`

e.g.

```
// attach the handler on the DOM to include all dynamically generated controls, too
$(document).on('click', '.customSelectBox', function() {
   // to get the one that was clicked
   var $this = $(this);
   // do the rest 
});
```

Comment: @Hero1134 - yes it is. post your problematic code rather than just saying "it's not working"

Comment: Yea, i did. I implement an alert('hello') to check. But it isn't working on my side. Thanks.

Comment: @Hero1134 - are you trolling me? show us the **code** that doesn't work by editing your question

Comment: Because it's running as part of a data bound template is it  possible that the html written out by the asp.net server has a different id because there are multiple radio buttons? Maybe you can cut and paste the html the server actually generates. Or add a generic jquery function like the one in this article to figure out the id when you click on any radio button? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680735/how-to-get-the-id-of-the-element-clicked-using-jquery

Comment: @joel that's why I'm suggesting the use of the css class

Comment: I agree, your class reference should work. A sample of the code would help.

Answer (score 0):

use partial id like below

```
$('[id*="rbAccessMode"]').click(
    function() { $(this).addClass("yourClass");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the ID for assigning a function to the click event for 2 reasons.

You use `ClientIDMode="Static"`, so there will be muliple ID's on the page with the same value.

Even if you would remove `ClientIDMode="Static"`, you are still not able to use the ID `rbAccessMode` because it is in a Control that repeats data, `rbAccessMode` will be turned into something like this `lsvAccessMode_rbAccessMode_2` to ensure there are no duplicate ID's.

Remove all the `ClientIDMode="Static"` attributes and assign the click event based on the class name.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".customSelectBox").click(function () {
            $(this).addClass("yourClass");
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, I managed to solved the question with all your help. Thanks to Joel and Ted's suggestions, I have changed the DOM structure of my code. Thanks to VDWWD, I have removed the ClientIDMode="Static" and got it working. Below is my working code.

```
    $(document).on('click', '#selectorBox', function () {
        $(this).children().addClass('active');
    });


<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lsvAccessMode" ClientIDMode="Static" OnItemDataBound="lsvAccessMode_ItemDataBound">
 <ItemTemplate>
     <div id="selectorBox" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12" runat="server" clientIDMode="Static">
         <asp:RadioButton runat="server" CssClass="customSelectBox disabled" ID="rbAccessMode" GroupName="accessMode" Enabled='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsSelected"))%>'  />
             <div class="customBox disabled" id="customBox">
                <strong><%# Eval("Decode1") %></strong><br>
                   <img src="<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>" style="height: 80px"><br>
                       <span class="help-block"><%# Eval("Decode2") %></span>
              </div>
      </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I added an additional ID in the parent class So instead of calling the button directly, I called its parent then navigate down using the .children() method. Thank you all once again. Hope my post could help people especially beginners who are new to asp.net.